# Should I flag to migrate questions to another SE site when I am not active there

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, flags, migration, migration-rejection

I recently flagged some questions for migration from StackOverflow to another StackExchange site (wordpress.stackexchange.com in this case). Some of these flags where declined by a moderator (reason: "Don't migrate crap") which was absolutely OK, as I wasn't aware of that rule then, and thought that these questions could be improved on the other site better than on StackOverflow.

However, for one of those flags the moderator stated: "[...] you should stop flagging WordPress questions unless you're actually active there [...]" Given that I was flagging some low-quality-questions for migration instead of flagging them as low-quality the moderator probably simply was annoyed by these flags. Sorry for that - now I know better.

I have quite some knowledge about WordPress and its ecosystem, having developed several plugins and themes myself. So I judge myself able to see whether a question is focused on Wordpress and its API or a general progamming question suited for StackOverflow.

So here's my question: Should I flag posts suited for other SE sites even if I am not active there but generally know the site's topic or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if you know the subject matter of the putative target site quite well, it is probably better if you don't flag unless you are really active on the site. This saves all sorts of problems down the line (the main one - don't migrate crap - you have discovered).

This isn't a hard and fast rule - it can't be - you may find the perfect question posted on the wrong site, but your normal thinking should be:

1. Is it off topic?
2. Is it a really good question but just on the wrong site?

   1. If "no" then vote/flag for simple closure.
   2. If "yes" then vote/flag for migration.

You can seen that migration is the last option. It has to pass through the other filters first.

Comment: Thank you for clarifiaction.

Answer (score 2):

I am that mod :)  I did feel a wee bit bad declining your flags because I know they were raised with good intentions, but some of those questions were fairly low quality affairs.

When I see a rapid succession of migration flags for a particular site from a single user then I usually have a quick look to see what level of participation there is on the destination site.

If there's little or no participation, and the questions are on the wrong side of borderline, then I'll advise throttling back - unfortunately there's limited space in the decline message so the advice/explanation may seem a little terse/curt - which was not intended.

In addition to [Chris's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149088/419), if you're flagging for a migration then ask yourself whether you could actually have a decent stab at answering the question if it appeared on the destination site, and without having to ask the OP twenty questions to get anywhere.

Unless you're willing to fix a poor or borderline question before requesting a migration then it's a wee bit unfair to expect the destination site's accommodate such posts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kev - especially the last two sentences were a good addendum to @ChrisF's answer.